# how to add 2 wheels at turtlebot3

Tags: ros

I want to add two wheels to the existing turtlebot model and call it to the gazebo and operate it using teleopkey, but the rear wheels don't work. I think it's a diff_drive plugin problem, but how do I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I'm referencing [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68167574/6069586) on how to edit the turtlebot(3) URDF model. While that's focusing more on Lidar, the nature of the plugins are the same for the wheels.

If you want to add two *cosmetic* wheels, making a copy of the specific turtlebot3 URDF file into your local package, and adding two wheels is as easy as adding another link (or two) of where the wheels are with respect to base_link, and their size/attributes.

If you want another set of driving wheels, there may be an issue with why you want to. The [gazebo plugins](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=ros_gzplugins), such as diff drive, needed to run the robot are already in the model. If you're trying to add another diff drive, you'll have issues. Try to re-use the existing diff drive plugin in the model, modify or tweak the settings.

As for other issues: have you confirmed that it's receiving commands? If you're using `teleopkey` node to send a (geometry_msgs/Twist) msg on topic `cmd_vel`, and the diff drive is supposed to listen on `cmd_vel`, have you checked that they're both pointing to the same topic (instead of `turtlebot3/cmd_vel`)? Are you loading your robot into gazebo correctly?